# How to change the mobile safari's default text "0 items" when using the "multiple" attribute of the "select" tag?

Tags: html

I am using the "**multiple**" attribute in the html tag "**select**".

```
<select multiple>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>                         
</select>
```

In the mobile safari, by default it shows "**0 items**" in the box. When I am selecting more than 1 items, say 3 then it shows "**3 items**" in the box.

*Is it possible to change the default text from "0 items" to something else like "Select option(s)"?*

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Here's what you need: For your first option, simply add

```
<option disabled selected class="hidden">Select option(s)</option>
```

where class hidden is simply:

```
.hidden { display:none; }
```

Then on focus, remove the "selected" attribute / property of the first option using jquery:

```
$('select').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).children(':first-child').removeProp('selected');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Chrome and IE though, <option> tags don't support styles like display:none, so you'll still see it in those browsers unless you use browser detection (yuck) to remove it.

Comment: The OP did specifically ask about Safari to be fair